# javascript security: prevent user from calling function from console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

Say I have the following script:

```
$("#mmyButton").click(function (){
if(condition){
      SaveVal(3);
}
});


var SaveValue = function (x){
// use Ajax to save x to server
}
```

Now my concern is that the user can open browser console and use `SaveValue(677)`

In such case all the logic of my code will be useless and the user can abuse my function communicating with the server

My question is:
Is there any way that I can prevent this?

Is there any security measures I should take?

Is this a valid place to utilize antiforgerytoken?

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: use validation on the server side !

Comment: not possible to prevent function calling from console

Comment: You can't stop client-side change. You need to confirm the action is valid for the current user on the server. What identify framework are you using?

Comment: No matter what you do, I can still view the requests sent to the server and spoof it there. There is *fundamentally* nothing you can do at the client to prevent this and as @cme64 says, your defense should be at the server side.

Comment: You can make sure the function is not in the global scope which makes it impossible to call directly from the console BUT as @spender says, there's nothing stopping someone opening up Fiddler2 and sending all sorts of weird and wonderful things to your server.

Comment: @CME64 how can I validate On the server that the function is called from console or called from button click??

Comment: check the variables that validate it, for example, if the function requires the user to be premium, get the username from the session and then check in the db if the user is a premium, if so then he is allowed to use code x if not then ignore it or return an error page .. other wrong values can be striped out using less than and greater than

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie asp identity